# Site submitted via Google Search Console API but not found on Google Search Console UI

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, api

I submitted client site via Google Search Console API successfully, I have even received a successful verification through the API, but it never makes it to the Search Console UI.

I waited 12 hours and I did a Google search "site:example.com" but I do not see any results.

Is Search Console API totally different form the Search Console UI? If not, why is my site submitted successfully via the API not showing up on the Console UI?

Comment: It takes much more than 12 hours for a site to begin showing up in Google search. Expect days if not weeks. Most sites take 1-2 months before really showing any significant results. I do not know about the API, however, if you have the chance, try the Search Console UI and do a Fetch as Google of the home page and then Submit to Index. Still it can take a couple of days and is not immediate so patience is required. Search engines are not real-time! Cheers!!

Comment: What I concerned most is although it submitted successfully via the API, it's not showing on the UI which is confusing.

Comment: I have no idea what the behavior should be using the API versus UI. There may be people here who do. There are some real experts here. Let's hope one of them has an idea for you. I am thinking time. Search engines are notoriously slow and the Google Search Console can definitely be slow. It is often a few days behind. Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you. I hope there is someone from Google could clear the confusion. It's really a surprise if Search Console API is not sharing the same data with Search Console UI.